# Subtract height from column

Tags: tables, spacing, margins

The following latex example is kicking the third table down to the second page. But I don't need it on the second page, I need it all on the first and currently it's set at `3.5in` but I really need it like 4 or 4.5.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=5.375in,paperheight=8.375in,margin=1.69in]{geometry}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\CenterWallPaper{1}{fac.png}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} p{1.65in} l @{} }
\hspace{-0.75in}\textbf{date} & \textbf{date}\vspace{-0.06in} \\
\multicolumn{2}{ l }{\hspace{-0.75in}\textbf{to}\vspace{-0.07in}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{ l }{\hspace{-1.05in}\textbf{letters}} \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.70in}

\hspace{-1.2in}\begin{tabular}{ @{} p{0.5in} p{3.25in} p{0.5in} @{} }
\textbf{date} & \hspace{-0.25in}\textbf{date} & \textbf{date} \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{3.5in}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} p{0.5in} p{0.5in} @{} }
\textbf{date} & \textbf{date} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It's the `.5` that does it as with `.4` it doesn't.  Any hints?

Comment: Increase the text block height `textheight` (as part of your  [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) settings). Would that be an option, or why do you have such specific margin and stock settings?

Comment: Doesn't seem to, I tried all the way up to `4in` and it doesn't seem to change anything :( `\usepackage[paperwidth=5.375in,paperheight=8.375in,margin=1.69in,textheight=4in]{geometry}`

Comment: you don't want textheight=4in that is tiny! also replace the `\vspace{3.5in}` by `\vspace{\fill}` then it will push the table down to the bottom of the page (if you specify a textheight big enough to hold three tables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you have a text block height of 8.375in-2(1.69in)=4.995in, which doesn't support your requirements. Using

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.375in,paperheight=8.375in,
  left=1.69in,right=1.69in,
  top=0.2in,bottom=0.2in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
```

leaves a text block height of 7.975in, which accommodates your needs. Of course, you can change the margins to your liking.

Comment: I kinda thought it had to do with margins, I just couldn't for the life of me figure out how to set them. Thanks.